# Draw a line between 2 selected points in a chart in wpf using mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, graphics, telerik, prism

Okay, I have the data from which i am drawing charts using telerik in WPF using mvvm and in Prism. Is there any guide i can use as a reference? i need to draw a line between 2 points of the chart.

Comment: What have you got so far? you might get more answers if you show what you've tried.

Comment: the problem is that i am new to telerik controls and dont know anything about it. all i need for now is a guide to go through with it. the application i am working on draws charts using telerik controls.

Comment: You might want to check out their tutorials on http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/introduction.html